# BeginTransaction requires an open connection. The connection's current state is Open, Executing

Tags: c#, .net, db2

When I run the following code I get the

> "BeginTransaction requires an open connection. The connection's
>   current state is Open, Executing"

exception.

```
using (var con = new IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection(
                         "Server=localhost;Database=SAMPLE;UID=***;PWD=***;"))
{
    con.Open();
    var c = con.CreateCommand();
    c.CommandText = "select * from DB2TEST";
    using (var r = c.ExecuteReader())
    {
        r.Read();
        con.BeginTransaction();// The exception is thrown here!!!
    }
}
```

I know that if I move the Begin transaction to an earlier time in the code it'll work - but that doesn't cut it.
I need to iterate a very large reader and open and close transactions as I want.

I tried ExecuteResultSet - but got the same behavior.

Comment: Clearly you need to begin the transaction before ExecuteReader.  What do you mean "open and close transactions as I want".

Comment: I need to open a transaction while it's reading. Oracle supports that.
With SQL server I use server side cursors

Comment: Could not even update without a transaction on an open data reader.  Need a separate command for the update.  Something to be aware of is DataReader will grab multiple rows for speed so if you update the next row you may get stale data from the DataReader.  I use a server cursor in that situation as it does not suffer from stale data.

Comment: @Blam how do you user a server cursor with db2?

Comment: Sorry I use MS SQL.  I just assumed DB2 had a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigations I figured out that I should use the "ExecutePageReader" which is the DB2 equivalent of ServerSideCursors in SQL.

So Instead of opening the reader and beginning the transaction while it's option. I fetch 40 rows, close the reader, do what ever I want with transactions, and then use the  "ExecutePageReader" to fetch the next 40 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are trying to start a transaction while the connection has an open data reader.

You have a couple of options:

1) read all the data you need into memory, close the reader, then start your transactions.

2) open 2 connections. Use one for reading and one for writing with your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select with update intent, that will create a IU (Intent update) lock for each row, and the you can convert it to IX (intent exclusive), and in that state you can do your transaction. That is easier if you use SQLJ.